# SQL server in Azure : inner join equivalent to left join here?

Tags: sql, sql-server

*SQL Server Version :  Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8  Oct  1 2020 18:48:35    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation*

In the most recent versions of SQL server (circa 2020), **is SQL server able to optimize inner joins,** or is it relevant to use a left join where appropriate?

**In other words :  Is this query...**

```
select * from MiddleTable
left join LeftTable on MiddleTable.LeftTableId = LeftTable.Id
inner join RightTable on MiddleTable.RightTableId = RightTable.Id
where LeftTable.SomeExtraFilterId = RightTable.SomeExtraFilterId 
and RightTable.AnotherExtraFilterId = 'whatever Id value'
```

**...significantly more efficient than this query,** as I would expect? :

```
select * from LeftTable
innerjoin MiddleTable on MiddleTable.LeftTableId = LeftTable.Id
inner join RightTable on MiddleTable.RightTableId = RightTable.Id
where LeftTable.SomeExtraFilterId = RightTable.SomeExtraFilterId 
and RightTable.AnotherExtraFilterId = 'whatever Id value'
```

**Bonus question : Does my question make sense?** Or did I completely misunderstand how joins work -- i.e.  it's never been a difference in performance (i.e. a difference in the number of combinations of rows), but instead just a syntactic difference (depending on which table you want to start the query with) ?

=========

**EDIT :**
I used SET STATISTICS IO ON and SET STATISTICS TIME ON to compare the queries execution.

- Result for the two inner joins :

  (163 rows affected)
  Table 'LeftTable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 326, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

  Table 'MiddleTable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 13, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

  Table 'RightTable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

  SQL Server Execution Times:
  CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.
  Total execution time: 00:00:00.040
- Resut for left join + inner join :

(same as above, but with half the logical reads on RightTable but double the time in execution).

**I don't know how much of this is called by the margin of error (it's too fast to be sure) but I'm accepting that the two queries are not significantly different, like I thought.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the execution plans.  In general, the two queries are equivalent, because the second `on` clause turns the outer join into an `inner join`.  Often, it is a `where` clause that does the filtering.

In many cases, the outer join and inner join versions are going to produce very similar execution plans, so the performance would be quite similar.

In general, an outer join puts more constraints on the optimizer than an inner join, so inner joins generally have more opportunity for optimization than outer joins.  (There are edge cases where the inner join execution plan is suboptimal and the outer join fixes that.)

Detecting the cases where an outer join is filtered to be an inner join is fairly trivial in this case, but more complicated in other cases.  I don't know how extensive databases are on finding such patterns.  In general, database developers do not focus on optimizing poorly written queries.

But, overall, you should write the query that you intend.  In this case, the desired query appears to be an inner join, so you should use that.

Comment: Perfect answer. I used  SET STATISTICS IO ON and SET STATISTICS TIME ON and updated the question